Why is this position winning for black?
[fen "r3kbnr/ppp2ppp/2n1p3/5q2/2B5/8/PPPP1P1P/R1BQK1NR w KQkq - 0 8"] 

White to move.
I was analyzing one of my games and saw this variation. Why is this position winning for black according to my engine? Black is winning only one pawn. There are no big threats, no pins.
Stockfish is showing that it is -3 which generally means that black has won.

If it's black turn qe4 attacks king and rook

How can the material be equal when black has an extra pawn?

@Lucenaposition I corrected my post

@cmgchess It is white to move

White's knigside might be weak because of white's lost g-pawn.

W lost a crucial pawn on g2, which makes his kingside weak. Plus B has a lead in development. I'd say -2 (if it's W's move).

First of all, at least for me Stockfish 16 shows -2 and not -3.
Black has more solid pawn structure, White has isolated pawns. At the moment there is the threat of Qe4+. Black has better development and it's also easier for him to develop the rest of the pieces. Black is ready to castle 0-0-0 while White is still far from getting his king to safety.
